# Joining two files using join and awk

Tags: bash, join, awk

I have the following file called file1:

```
j_2,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,11
j_7,2019-04-05,-9.78,,,,11
j_1,2019-04-01,20.00,,,,22
j_4,2019-04-04,130.00,,,,22
j_8,2019-04-05,-250.00,,,,22
j_1,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,33
j_3,2019-04-01,-264.56,,,,33
j_5,2019-04-04,130.00,,,,44
j_6,2019-04-04,-12.90,,,,55
j_9,2019-04-08,100.00,,,,66
```

and file2

```
11,Accounting,VE
22,Paint,VE
33,Legal,VE
44,Office,VE
55,Maintenance,VE
66,IT,VE
```

I want to join file1 (on column 7) and file2 (on column 1) to create file3.

```
j_2,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,Accounting,VE
j_7,2019-04-05,-9.78,,,,Accounting,VE
j_1,2019-04-01,20.00,,,,Paint,VE
j_4,2019-04-04,130.00,,,,Paint,VE
j_8,2019-04-05,-250.00,,,,Paint,VE
j_1,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,Legal,VE
j_3,2019-04-01,-264.56,,,,Legal,VE
j_5,2019-04-04,130.00,,,,Office,VE
j_6,2019-04-04,-12.90,,,,Maintenance,VE
j_9,2019-04-08,100.00,,,,IT,VE
```

I have tried

```
join -t ',' -1 7 -2 1 file1 file2 | head -n 2
```

which results in

```
11,j_2,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,Accounting,VE
11,j_7,2019-04-05,-9.78,,,,Accounting,VE
```

Why does a 11, appear in the front and how can I run the join command to get the required result.
Furthermore, I also want to be able to do this in awk. I have looked on the internet for solutions and found this but don't understand it fully to apply it to my context. Also would I be able to pass file2 and file1 as variables as I really want to be using this as part of a bash script.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} NR==FNR {h[$1] = $2; next} {print $0,h[$1]}' file2 file1
```

Help is always much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a _specific problem_ you have when trying to expand shell variables into filenames on the awk command line? Note that generally we want you to have actually _tried_ your code so you can ask about a specific thing that doesn't work; "please explain this code I found on the Internet" questions are in general [taken _very_ badly here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253894/how-to-handle-explain-how-this-code-dump-works-questions).

Comment: You'd need to change `$1` to refer to the actual join column, and `$2` to refer to the data you want to store, but in general it looks like the all-in-awk approach is _very_ close to what you need already.

Comment: Big problem with `join` with your existing code, btw, is that both inputs need to be _sorted on the join key_; that way `join` can operate in constant memory and linear time.

Comment: Sorry I had actually sorted file1 before using join. I have updated file1 to reflect that. My apologies.

Comment: Charles Duffy, I have tried h[$7] = $2 .......[$7], h[$1] = $7.......[$1] but nothing works. As mentioned I do not fully understand the logic behind the awk code, hence the question.

Comment: **Don't change rules when you have response(s)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering OP's question about why the join column is showing up at the beginning of the line ...

If no explicit format (`-o FORMAT`) is provided then `join` uses a default ouput format (from `man join`):

> Default FORMAT outputs the join field, (then) the remaining
> fields from FILE1, (then) the remaining fields from FILE2

OP will need to provide an explicit format which can get tedious if there are several columns (`join` does not provide any sort of wildcard/range/regex designators).  One example

```
join -t',' -1 7 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.2,2.3 file1 file2
```

---

Another issue which doesn't show up in OP's sample `head -2` output, but is mentioned in the ccomments, is that `join` requires both files to be sorted by the join column.

In my system OP's `join` comand generates the following error strewn output:

```
$ join -t ',' -1 7 -2 1 file1 file2
22,j_1,2019-04-01,20.00,,,,Paint,VE
join: file1:3: is not sorted: j_2,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,11
33,j_1,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,Legal,VE
44,j_5,2019-04-04,130.00,,,,Office,VE
55,j_6,2019-04-04,-12.90,,,,Maintenance,VE
66,j_9,2019-04-08,100.00,,,,IT,VE
join: input is not in sorted order
```

---

Pulling this all together into a single `join` command:

```
$ join -t ',' -1 7 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.2,2.3 <(sort -t ',' -k7,7 file1) <(sort -t ',' -k1,1 file2)
j_2,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,Accounting,VE
j_7,2019-04-05,-9.78,,,,Accounting,VE
j_1,2019-04-01,20.00,,,,Paint,VE
j_4,2019-04-04,130.00,,,,Paint,VE
j_8,2019-04-05,-250.00,,,,Paint,VE
j_1,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,Legal,VE
j_3,2019-04-01,-264.56,,,,Legal,VE
j_5,2019-04-04,130.00,,,,Office,VE
j_6,2019-04-04,-12.90,,,,Maintenance,VE
j_9,2019-04-08,100.00,,,,IT,VE
```

**NOTE:** if you know for a fact that a file is already sorted by the join column then you can replace the associated `<(sort -t ',' -kx,x file)` with `file`

Because of the hassles of having to explicitly list all output columns I'd probably opt for something in `awk` ...

---

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN   { FS=OFS="," }

FNR==NR { suffix[$1] = $2 OFS $3; next }         # 1st file: store data in array suffix[]

        { if ($NF in suffix) {                   # 2nd file: if last column ($NF==$7 in this case) is an index in the suffix[] array ...
             for (i=1;i<NF;i++)                  # loop through the 1st to (NF-1)th columns ...
                 printf "%s%s", $i, OFS          # print each one to stdout then ...
             print suffix[$NF]                   # finish off current line of output with the value stored in the array location
          }
        }
' file2 <(sort -t ',' -k7,7 file1)               # no need to sort file2 as we will just be doing lookups against the suffix[] array;
                                                 # sort file1 so the output is generated in the same order as OP's desired result
```

This generates:

```
j_2,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,Accounting,VE
j_7,2019-04-05,-9.78,,,,Accounting,VE
j_1,2019-04-01,20.00,,,,Paint,VE
j_4,2019-04-04,130.00,,,,Paint,VE
j_8,2019-04-05,-250.00,,,,Paint,VE
j_1,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,Legal,VE
j_3,2019-04-01,-264.56,,,,Legal,VE
j_5,2019-04-04,130.00,,,,Office,VE
j_6,2019-04-04,-12.90,,,,Maintenance,VE
j_9,2019-04-08,100.00,,,,IT,VE
```

Comment: Thanks markp-fuso for this. All works and well explained.

Answer (score 1):

assuming sorted input files

```
$ join -t, -17 file1 file2 | cut -d, -f2-

j_2,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,Accounting,VE
j_7,2019-04-05,-9.78,,,,Accounting,VE
j_1,2019-04-01,20.00,,,,Paint,VE
j_4,2019-04-04,130.00,,,,Paint,VE
j_8,2019-04-05,-250.00,,,,Paint,VE
j_1,2019-04-01,100.00,,,,Legal,VE
j_3,2019-04-01,-264.56,,,,Legal,VE
j_5,2019-04-04,130.00,,,,Office,VE
j_6,2019-04-04,-12.90,,,,Maintenance,VE
j_9,2019-04-08,100.00,,,,IT,VE
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine but what does join -17 do? I had a look through the man pages and can't find any numbering option like that.

Comment: It means use the 7th field as the key for the first file, the notation may seen cryptic I agree. The space between the key and value is optional `-1 7` may be more readable.